# Should large flexbox flex-values be avoided?

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a block with 2 blocks in, where block1 takes up 90% of the space and block2 takes up 10% of the space, approximately. This works fine in most browsers, however in IE 11 block1 takes up too much space (~97%) which hides most of block2. This is, as seen in the code below, with flex: 1 and flex: 0. If I, however, change the values to flex: 10 and flex: 0 for the blocks it works fine in all browsers.

```
.block1 {
    flex: 1;  // --> 9
}

.block2 {
    flex: 0;  // --> 1
}
```

So to my question; is there any reason I should avoid this approach? If so, what would be a better solution?

For some context to what we're dealing with; it's a horizontally streching notification bar with a main text message and close-button.

Horrible reconstruction:

```
                                   Centered text                                    [Close]
```

Comment: should not it be: flex:1; and flex:9; ?

Comment: The specific percentages are not important, but yes - for the values i mentioned I suppose you're right! I'll change that

Comment: I would suggest that you are overthinking this. Unless the percentages are vital, the right element doesn't need to have **any** flex value. Leave it alone and it will just be its natural size. Then just give the left element `flex:1`

Comment: I would allocate 10% to block2 with `flex: 0 0 10%` and then allocate the rest of the space to block 1 with `flex: 1`

Comment: Thank you. @Danield - your solution felt a bit more controlled and worked sort of fine. At least it gives the same results in different browsers. Since no one answered the question directly I'm going to guess that is a legit way to do it, as your answers seem to imply. If you'd like an accepted answer, just copypaste your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate 10% to block2 with `flex: 0 0 10%` and then allocate the rest of the space to block 1 with `flex: 1`

Demo

```css
.wpr {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.block1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: aqua;
}
.block2 {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="block1">block 1</div>
  <div class="block2">block 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `display: flex` with simple 10 to 90% ratio sharings?

> **PRO TIP:** When using `flex-grow` , you should include another content wrapper within the flexed element (if it is supposed to be with a fixed width) to avoid content-squeeze.

That might be a browser-specific prefix issue. I suggest using an **[Auto-Prefixer plugin](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)** with Your editor of choice. Bad thing is, prefixes for Flex-box are way too many for one to handle evenly cross-browser-wise. So if You are using SASS, I will advise You to use a mixin Library like **[Bourbon.io](http://bourbon.io/docs/#flexbox)** which produces all the prefix weight for You.

If You do not, then I suggest you start learning the **[prefix mess](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)** that Flexbox comes with.